# multiple select salva tudo no banco, como salvar só o que escolhi no select?

Tags: php, html, html-select

tenho um multiple select no meu form, o que acontece é que quando submeto o form, ele ta salvando todos os Options no banco, eu queria que ele gravasse no banco somente aqueles que eu cliquei no select
Exemplo: cliquei somente em (SEGUNDA,TERCA) ai ele gravaria só isso no banco, só que ele ta gravando como se eu tivesse selecionado SEGUNDA,TERCA,QUARTA,QUINTA,SEXTA,SABADO e DOMINGO, segue meu código abaixo me ajudem por favor:

pagina do select seleciono isso aqui somente.

Código do FORM:

```
<div class="form-group">
           <h1>Selecione os dias dos Ensaios:</h1>
          <select multiple class="form-control" name="diaensaio[]" id="diaensaio">
                   <option>SEGUNDA</option>
                   <option>TERCA</option>
                   <option>QUARTA</option>
                   <option>QUINTA</option>
                   <option>SEXTA</option>
                   <option>SABADO</option>
                   <option>DOMINGO</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

Código da pagina que faz a inserção no banco.

salvarFichaCadastralMusica.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$codUsuario = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];
$ieqbairro = strtoupper($_POST['ieqbairro']);
$pastor = strtoupper($_POST['pastor']);
$lider = strtoupper($_POST['lider']);
$celulaAtivas = strtoupper($_POST['celulasativas']);
$participantes = strtoupper($_POST['participantescelulas']);
$quantidadereunioes = strtoupper($_POST['quantidadereunioes']);
$quantidaensamensal = strtoupper($_POST['quantidaensamensal']);
/*$diaensaio = strtoupper($_POST['diaensaio']);*/
$horaensaio = strtoupper($_POST['horaensaio']);
$totalmembrosdepartamento = strtoupper($_POST['totalmembrosdepartamento']);
$vocal = strtoupper($_POST['vocal']);
$mulhercontralto = strtoupper($_POST['mulhercontralto']);
$mezzosoprano = strtoupper($_POST['mezzosoprano']);
$soprano = strtoupper($_POST['soprano']);
$homensbaixo = strtoupper($_POST['homensbaixo']);
$baritono = strtoupper($_POST['baritono']);
$tenor = strtoupper($_POST['tenor']);
$guitarra = strtoupper($_POST['guitarrista']);
$baterista = strtoupper($_POST['bateristas']);
$tecladista = strtoupper($_POST['tecladistas']);
$violao = strtoupper($_POST['violao']);
$baixo = strtoupper($_POST['baixistas']);
$meialua = strtoupper($_POST['meialua']);
$cajon = strtoupper($_POST['cajon']);
$outros = strtoupper($_POST['outros']);
$ministeriodecarreira = strtoupper($_POST['ministeriocarreira']);
$descrinomemstcarreira = strtoupper($_POST['nomeministeriocarreira']);
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');

$diaensaio = '';
foreach($_POST['diaensaio'] as $s){
    $diaensaio .= ',' . $s;
}
//para remover a primeira virgula
$diaensaio = ltrim($diaensaio, ',');

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ficha_Cadastral_Musica (CodUsuario,ieqbairro, pastor, lider, celulaAtivas, participantescelulas, quantidadereunioes, quantidaensamensal,diaensaio, horaensaio, totalmenbrosminis, vocalquant, mulhercontralto, mulhermezzosoprano, mulhersoprano, homensbaixo, homensbaritono, homenstenor, guitarraqtd, bateristaqtd, tecladistaqtd, violaoqtd, baixoqtd, meialuaqtd, cajonqtd, outros, ministeriodecarreira, descrinomemstcarreira) VALUES ('$codUsuario','$ieqbairro', '$pastor', '$lider', '$celulaAtivas', '$participantes', '$quantidadereunioes', '$quantidaensamensal', '$diaensaio', '$horaensaio', '$totalmembrosdepartamento','$vocal', '$mulhercontralto', '$mezzosoprano','$soprano', '$homensbaixo', '$baritono', '$tenor', '$guitarra', '$baterista', '$tecladista', '$violao', '$baixo', '$meialua', '$cajon', '$outros', '$ministeriodecarreira', '$descrinomemstcarreira')") or die('Erro ao inserir ao banco de dados'); 

if($query){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Dados Salvos com sucesso!');window.location.href='menuMusica.php'</script>";

    }

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Agora veja como a informação foi salva no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o resultado de `var_dump($_POST['diaensaio[]']);`?

Comment: @Costamilam você fala o que gravou no banco de dados ?

Comment: Ao submeter o formulá para a página PHP que salva no banco (colocando esse trecho), qual o resultado?

Comment: @Costamilam voce fala colocar no meu codigo assim $diaensaio = '';
foreach($_POST['diaensaio'] as $s){
    $diaensaio .= ',' . $s;
}
//para remover a primeira virgula
$diaensaio = ltrim($diaensaio, ',');

var_dump($_POST['diaensaio[]']); 

e submeter o formulario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só fazer um `implode` na array usando a vírgula como separador dos valores:

```
$diaensaio = implode(",", $_POST['diaensaio']);
```

Suponhamos que foram selecionados os dias SEGUNDA, QUARTA E QUINTA, com o `implode` o resultado já será os valores separados por vírgula:

```
SEGUNDA,QUARTA,QUINTA
```

Seu código ficaria assim (repare na linha abaixo do comentário `// dias dos ensaio`):

```
<?php

session_start();

$codUsuario = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];
$ieqbairro = strtoupper($_POST['ieqbairro']);
$pastor = strtoupper($_POST['pastor']);
$lider = strtoupper($_POST['lider']);
$celulaAtivas = strtoupper($_POST['celulasativas']);
$participantes = strtoupper($_POST['participantescelulas']);
$quantidadereunioes = strtoupper($_POST['quantidadereunioes']);
$quantidaensamensal = strtoupper($_POST['quantidaensamensal']);
// dias dos ensaio
$diaensaio = implode(",", $_POST['diaensaio']);
$horaensaio = strtoupper($_POST['horaensaio']);
$totalmembrosdepartamento = strtoupper($_POST['totalmembrosdepartamento']);
$vocal = strtoupper($_POST['vocal']);
$mulhercontralto = strtoupper($_POST['mulhercontralto']);
$mezzosoprano = strtoupper($_POST['mezzosoprano']);
$soprano = strtoupper($_POST['soprano']);
$homensbaixo = strtoupper($_POST['homensbaixo']);
$baritono = strtoupper($_POST['baritono']);
$tenor = strtoupper($_POST['tenor']);
$guitarra = strtoupper($_POST['guitarrista']);
$baterista = strtoupper($_POST['bateristas']);
$tecladista = strtoupper($_POST['tecladistas']);
$violao = strtoupper($_POST['violao']);
$baixo = strtoupper($_POST['baixistas']);
$meialua = strtoupper($_POST['meialua']);
$cajon = strtoupper($_POST['cajon']);
$outros = strtoupper($_POST['outros']);
$ministeriodecarreira = strtoupper($_POST['ministeriocarreira']);
$descrinomemstcarreira = strtoupper($_POST['nomeministeriocarreira']);
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');
mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');


$query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ficha_Cadastral_Musica (CodUsuario,ieqbairro, pastor, lider, celulaAtivas, participantescelulas, quantidadereunioes, quantidaensamensal,diaensaio, horaensaio, totalmenbrosminis, vocalquant, mulhercontralto, mulhermezzosoprano, mulhersoprano, homensbaixo, homensbaritono, homenstenor, guitarraqtd, bateristaqtd, tecladistaqtd, violaoqtd, baixoqtd, meialuaqtd, cajonqtd, outros, ministeriodecarreira, descrinomemstcarreira) VALUES ('$codUsuario','$ieqbairro', '$pastor', '$lider', '$celulaAtivas', '$participantes', '$quantidadereunioes', '$quantidaensamensal', '$diaensaio', '$horaensaio', '$totalmembrosdepartamento','$vocal', '$mulhercontralto', '$mezzosoprano','$soprano', '$homensbaixo', '$baritono', '$tenor', '$guitarra', '$baterista', '$tecladista', '$violao', '$baixo', '$meialua', '$cajon', '$outros', '$ministeriodecarreira', '$descrinomemstcarreira')") or die('Erro ao inserir ao banco de dados'); 

if($query){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Dados Salvos com sucesso!');window.location.href='menuMusica.php'</script>";

    }

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

**Obs.:** o valor em `$_POST['diaensaio']` deve estar sempre cheio, senão vai causar erro no `implode`.

Comment: podiria me mostrar por gentileza como ficaria no codigo que postei acima ?

Comment: coloquei somente o que vc me passou, mais não salvou nada no banco.

tirei tudo isso aqui :

$diaensaio = ''; foreach($_POST['diaensaio'] as $s){ $diaensaio .= ',' . $s; } //para remover a primeira virgula $diaensaio = ltrim($diaensaio, ',');


E coloquei isso somente:

$diaensaio = implode(",", $_POST['diaensaio']);

Comment: mais precisa ter o foreach e depois o 

$diaensaio = implode(",", $_POST['diaensaio']);    ?

Comment: ele agora salvou no banco, mais ainda continua gravando tudo que esta no select e não o que eu selecionei sabe, ele ta gravando assim no banco:
Exemplo(SEGUNDA,QUARTA,QUINTA,SEXTA,SABADO,DOMINGO)
sendo que eu marquei so SEGUNDA e QUINTA

Comment: posta o codigo seu para eu ver aqui por favor

Comment: será que tem algo errado com meu insert ou meu html vou postar aqui

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO ficha_Cadastral_Musica (CodUsuario,ieqbairro, pastor, lider, celulaAtivas, participantescelulas, quantidadereunioes, quantidaensamensal,diaensaio, horaensaio, totalmenbrosminis, vocalquant, mulhercontralto, mulhermezzosoprano, mulhersoprano, homensbaixo, homensbaritono, homenstenor, guitarraqtd, bateristaqtd, tecladistaqtd, violaoqtd, baixoqtd, meialuaqtd, cajonqtd, outros, ministeriodecarreira, descrinomemstcarreira)

Comment: VALUES ('$codUsuario','$ieqbairro', '$pastor', '$lider', '$celulaAtivas', '$participantes', '$quantidadereunioes', '$quantidaensamensal', '$diaensaio', '$horaensaio', '$totalmembrosdepartamento','$vocal', '$mulhercontralto', '$mezzosoprano','$soprano', '$homensbaixo', '$baritono', '$tenor', '$guitarra', '$baterista', '$tecladista', '$violao', '$baixo', '$meialua', '$cajon', '$outros', '$ministeriodecarreira', '$descrinomemstcarreira')") or die('Erro ao inserir ao banco de dados');

Comment: <select multiple  name="diaensaio[]" id="diaensaio">
                       <option value="SEGUNDA">SEGUNDA</option>
                       <option value="TERCA">TERCA</option>
        <option value="QUARTA">QUARTA</option>
        <option value="QUINTA">QUINTA</option>
        <option value="SEXTA">SEXTA</option>
        <option value="SABADO">SABADO</option>
        <option value="DOMINGO">DOMINGO</option>
              </select>
          </div>

Comment: muito estranho quando eu dou um echo na tela para ver o que ta chegando, ele ta passando todos os dias da semana, não sei como resolver isso

Comment: consegui agora funcionou deu certo, eu tinha me esquecido que eu tinha criado uma função em javaScript que selecionava tudo que tinha no meu multiple select kkkkk, obrigado pela força